# Google BigQuery : number of sessions that visited a set of pages

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I've been working on a (Standard) SQL query of GA data to find the number of sessions that include either of two URLs. However, filtering by the two URLs and pulling from hits.page.pagePath is where I run into problems.

This is one example of a query that gives me errors:

```
SELECT
  date, COUNT(visitId) AS visits
FROM `123456789.ga_sessions_20170219`,`123456789.ga_sessions_20170220`
WHERE
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pagePath, r"^/(apples|oranges).html.*")
GROUP BY date
```

And straight up flattening doesn't work either:

```
SELECT
  date, COUNT(visitId) AS visits
FROM `123456789.ga_sessions_20170219`,`123456789.ga_sessions_20170220`
WHERE
  REGEXP_CONTAINS((
    SELECT pagePath
    FROM UNNEST(
      SELECT page
      FROM UNNEST(hits) AS page) AS pagePath), r"^/(apples|oranges).html.*")
GROUP BY date
```

Also, I'm not sure if this approach will give me the data I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you cannot use comma to `UNION` tables in standard SQL (comma means `CROSS JOIN`) - you can use `_TABLE_SUFFIX` or just straight `UNION ALL` instead.
And to count sessions which had hit on pages defined by regular expression, you can use the following `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT
  date, COUNT(visitId) AS visits
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM `123456789.ga_sessions_20170219` UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM `123456789.ga_sessions_20170220`)
WHERE
  EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) h
    WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagePath, r"^/(apples|oranges).html.*"))
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks! As you can see, some of my issues come from porting from Legacy SQL. Your example works perfectly -- I've verified the results against what I'm seeing in GA.